# w3wp.exe memory leak on mixed ASP classic/ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, iis, memory-leaks, asp-classic

I am working on a website that is running on Windows Server 2016 and IIS10.0 (although our production servers run Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS7) and recently discovered that it is leaking memory each time a page is loaded, either by going to a new page or refreshing the current one. The website uses a mix of ASP classic pages and ASP.NET (as the site is slowly being transitioned over to the latter).

Initially I found that a good chunk of the ASP classic pages did not properly close/dispose of their objects (e.g. ADODB recordsets), but after fixing that the leak is still present.

So then I created two completely barebones pages, one for aspx and one for asp, which contain nothing but the bare minimum requirements for HTML (and whatever respective necessities for the language such as the CodeFile line in the aspx page). Constantly refreshing both of these pages continues to produce the leak, which leads me to suspect it's an IIS configuration error.

I used DebugDiag to try and get a memory dump but the results seemed inconclusive as cachfile.dll and sqlncli11.dll appeared to be leaking the memory.

I then swapped to windbg, recycled the app pool, and loaded our simplest page once (that being our login page in ASP classic). Then, I attached windbg, dumped the heap with !dumpheap -stat and saved it, detached the debugger, refreshed the page 10 times, and repeated the dumping process. After sorting the data out and diffing the two dumps, it looks like HttpContext, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, and other related classes are living forever in memory and not releasing, as the object counts increased by roughly the same number of times the page was refreshed, give or take a bit, and no other obvious increases existed elsewhere. I also dumped the Session collection to be certain it somehow was not creating multiple sessions and it came out correctly with just one session with no variables stored.

This is a sample of what I saw on first load:

```
00007ff9611e12c0    90  5760    System.Web.HttpAsyncResult
00007ff9611e0348    16  6784    System.Web.HttpContext
00007ff9611e08f8    16  6272    System.Web.HttpRequest
```

And what I saw after 10 refreshes:

```
00007ff9611e12c0    990 63360   System.Web.HttpAsyncResult
00007ff9611e0348    166 70384   System.Web.HttpContext
00007ff9611e08f8    166 65072   System.Web.HttpRequest
```

So, final things I have done, but have produced no difference: disabling page caching entirely, reducing script timeout, and changing Request Queue Time-out. None of these have been able to stop the leak.

Has anyone experienced this before? Is there a way to fix it or a more in-depth method to figure out the exact cause of the memory leak? Is there some IIS setting I am missing that controls Request lifetime?

I have the two dumps I compared available below, if that is any help. I diffed these in Notepad++ to identify count/size discrepancies.
[First Page Load Dump](https://pastebin.com/uBETWC6g)
[10 Refreshes Dump](https://pastebin.com/kzy62ANZ)

Comment: "Constantly refreshing both of these pages continues to produce the leak"  Are you using any of the following:   If this happens for both then I would look for something that is consistent to both such as Session variables ....?

Comment: As I had mentioned (admittedly, a little buried), I made sure sessions were not the problem; the empty pages don't ever touch sessions in any way, and dumping the memory heap and tracing it to the session/session collection address shows that every 'stuck' HttpRequest et al are pointing at the same Session object.

Comment: Sorry, my bad for not reading carefully to the end.

Comment: +1 for the excellent diagnostics and write up. Am heading down the same gradual classic ASP to dot net route and same OS mix shortly. **Please please please** can you **post the solution if you find it outside of SO**. Thanks on behalf of the Classic ASP community.

Comment: I would gladly share my answer if I come upon one. Sadly, I have been at this for almost a week and have not gotten any further than what I have posted, particularly because other priorities have taken over for now.